# Changing msvcrt.dll on Windows System

Tags: mingw, msvcrt

I'm using MinGW 4.8.0 (posix, dwarf-2) for building c++ code. Looking with `dumpbin` I noticed the MinGW links to `msvcrt.dll` that on my on Windows 7 is at the version 7.0.7601.17744 and on Windows Xp SP3 is at version 7.0.2600.5512.

Well I want that MinGW links to a newer version to Microsoft C Runtime library so I've two choice: use a precompiled version of MinGW that arleady links to newr C Runtime or rename for example `msvcrt110.dll` to `msvcrt.dll` and deply the application with that library.

What do you think?

Comment: Note, that MinGW installation actually _contains_ import libraries for the newer msvcrt versions. But it does not seem to have any option in the spec to use them.

Comment: There is a discussion [in this thread](http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/fstat-and-msvcr-71-80-90-td16368.html), though it looks rather complicated.